# how to regress categorical variables in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm trying to do a multinomial logit and my independent variables are categorical. I have two categorical variables - `edu1` for those with high school degrees and `edu2` for those with college degrees. The variables are dummy variables (`edu1=1` denotes those with high school degrees, `edu1=0` without) I want the results so that I can compare results against those who have college degrees. However, when I do `mlogit edu*`, the model automatically includes `edu1` not `edu2` in the model. Is there way to reverse this and include `edu2` and not include `edu`1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both in the model unless you drop the constant. Google "dummy variable trap" to see why. Here's an example:

```
. webuse sysdsn1, clear
(Health insurance data)

. recode male (0=1) (1=0), gen(female)
(644 differences between male and female)

. mlogit insure male female, nocons nolog

Multinomial logistic regression                   Number of obs   =        616
                                                  Wald chi2(4)    =     149.44
Log likelihood = -553.40712                       Prob > chi2     =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      insure |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Indemnity    |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Prepaid      |
        male |   .3001046   .1703301     1.76   0.078    -.0337363    .6339455
      female |  -.1772065   .0968274    -1.83   0.067    -.3669847    .0125718
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Uninsure     |
        male |  -1.529395   .3059244    -5.00   0.000    -2.128996   -.9297944
      female |  -1.989585   .1884768   -10.56   0.000    -2.358993   -1.620177
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. mlogit insure male, nolog

Multinomial logistic regression                   Number of obs   =        616
                                                  LR chi2(2)      =       6.38
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0413
Log likelihood = -553.40712                       Pseudo R2       =     0.0057

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      insure |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Indemnity    |  (base outcome)
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Prepaid      |
        male |    .477311   .1959283     2.44   0.015     .0932987    .8613234
       _cons |  -.1772065   .0968274    -1.83   0.067    -.3669847    .0125718
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
Uninsure     |
        male |     .46019   .3593233     1.28   0.200    -.2440708    1.164451
       _cons |  -1.989585   .1884768   -10.56   0.000    -2.358993   -1.620177
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that in second specification, the constant is the female effect and males get constant plus the male coefficient. This matches what you get with the no constant specification above.

If you have other dummies in the model, things get a bit more complicated. The constant will correspond to all the omitted categories from each set of dummy variables.